# IntelliJ IDEA: Not able to run only multiple classes with main method

Tags: java, intellij-idea, ide

[image: Actual Screenshot]

I have created 2 classes with intelliJ , the first one is named main and second one is named feettoInches. Now after creating the first class i was able to run and compile main class. 
But after creating the second class , i.e feetToInches , I am not able to run it. It still run the first class.

Is there any setting i have to change?

Comment: Add code and error messages as text not as screenshot

Comment: Right-click on the class > Run, or alternatively Menu > Run > Edit Configurations

Comment: There is no option to run it @matoni and I dont get any errors since it runs the other class.

Comment: Google is your friend: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-applications.html

Comment: The **most** important thing here: screenshots are discouraged. Program code is **text**. Errors are **text**. A user that is around for 4 years really should know that such input is not accepted here. Please fix that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have imported the wrong `String` class. Check the `import` statement at the very top of your file. It should be `java.lang.String` instead.

Because of that the `main` method signature doesn't match the standard Java entry point which uses `java.lang.String` and you can't run this code.

As you don't need to import the classes from `java.lang.*` package explicitly, just remove the `import` statement to fix the problem.